# $S=\{(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...)|\sum_v \lambda_v^2<\infty\}$.Then$\sum_v \lambda_v \eta_v$ converges & $(x,y) =\sum_v \lambda_v\eta_v$ is inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, inner-products

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 191, it is asked that

> Consider the space $S$ of all infinite sequences $x = (\lambda_1,
> > \lambda_2, ...)$, where $\lambda_v \in \mathbb{R}$, such that  $$\sum_v \lambda_v^2 < \infty.$$ Show that
>   $\sum_v \lambda_v \eta_v$ converges and that the bilinear function
>   $(x,y) =\sum_v \lambda_v \eta_v$ is an inner product in $S$.

So how can we show this ?

I mean since the sum $\sum_v \lambda_v^2$ is finite, $\lim_{v\to \infty} \lambda_v^2$ = 0, hence $\lim_{v\to \infty} \lambda_v$ = 0.

Moreover, we also know that $\frac{1}{v} > \lambda_v^2$, so $\sqrt{\frac{1}{v}} > \lambda_v$, hence $\frac{1}{v} > \lambda_v \eta_V$, but this doesn't give me anything useful.

Comment: just to check $\lambda_v \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mdave16 yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a hint.

Remember that $2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$ for every pair of real numbers.

Comment: The proof is complete :).